# Expressing $\langle x,y\rangle$ in terms of $||x+y||$ and $||x-y||$

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

I am self studying  on Functional Analysis from notes of senior and I am struck on this problem.

Let (H, ||.||) be a Pre Hilbert Space on $K= \mathbb{R}$ and let $x,y \in H$. Express <x,y> in terms of ||x+y|| and ||x-y||.

I am not able to do much to able to solve this question.

I need only hints and I think the question is not hard.

Kindly give just a couple of hints.

Comment: Hint: for real numbers, we have $(a\pm b)^2=a^2\pm2ab+b^2 $. So how can you rearrange to get $ab$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the *polarization identity*

$$\langle x, y \rangle = \frac 1 4(\lVert x + y \rVert^2 - \lVert x - y \rVert^2) . $$
The proof is very easy:

$$\lVert x + y \rVert^2 - \lVert x - y \rVert^2 = \langle x +y , x+y \rangle -\langle x-y, x-y \rangle \\ = (\langle x, x \rangle + 2\langle x, y \rangle + \langle y, y \rangle) - (\langle x, x \rangle - 2\langle x, y \rangle + \langle y, y \rangle) \\ = 4 \langle x, y \rangle. $$

Comment: Thank you very much!